# How to use script in vue

Tags: vue.js

I am not very good at English, I will describe the problem as clearly as possible.

```
 <template>
  <div class="Index">
    <div
      class="content"
      v-html="content"
    ></div>
  </div>
</template>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      content: '',

    }
  },
  mounted() {
   // This data is returned by axios,This is rich text with lots of tags, including script
   this.content="<p>1111</p><div>222<div><script>alert() //There is a lot of code here.</script>"
 }
}
```

The console will report this error:

```
Syntax Error: SyntaxError: /Users/sinx/development/cxz/src/views/Index.vue: Unterminated template (33:19)
```

Now, the problem is how to insert the data returned by axios into vue using v-html. Thank you all.

The initial judgment seems to be due to the reason of `<script>`

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow :) It looks like your JS code should be inside a script tag like `<script> export default { .... } </script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the problem, if you want to render rich text, especially rich text with a srcipt tag, the tag needs to be escaped.
But,Although v-html can render tags, but can't execute the contents of the script, if I want to know how to execute the contents of the script, I have a way.

Answer (score 0):

Use axios...

axios.get function uses a Promise.
When the API returns data successfully, the code within the then block is executed.

```
   mounted() {
      axios.get(url).then(response => {
        this.results = response.data
      })
   }
```

Here is the link
[Using Axios to Consume APIs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html)
 from official site.

Comment: Thank you, This is not a problem with axios. The data I sent is transmitted using axios.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include your js code inside scripts tags, like below;

```
<script> include </script>
```

That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should put all your JS in the script tag. The basic structure of a Vue app is like this.

```
<template>
   //Your html here
</template>
<script>
  export default {
     data(){
        return {
           content : ""
         }
      },
     mounted(){
         axios.get(url).then(response => {
           this.content = response.data     //depends on the structure of response
         }).then(error => {
           console.log(error);
          });
        }
      }
<script>
```

Hope this helps :)